# bingx api How to get user balance with python

Tags: python, trading

This is the code I wrote to get user balance from BingX API. 
I think I do everything correct but it doesn't work properly.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64
import hmac
import time

APIURL = "https://open-api.bingx.com"
APIKEY = "MyApiKey"
SECRETKEY = "MySecretKey"

def genSignature(paramsStr):
    return hmac.new(SECRETKEY.encode("utf-8"),
        paramsStr.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()

def post(url, body):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'X-BX-APIKEY': APIKEY,
    }, method="GET")
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

def getBalance():
    paramsMap = {
        "timestamp": int(time.time()*1000)
    }
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (k, paramsMap[k]) for k in paramsMap])
    paramsStr += "&signature=" + genSignature(paramsStr).hex()
    url = "%s/openApi/swap/v2/user/balance?%s" % (APIURL, paramsStr)
    return post(url, paramsStr)

def main():
    print(getBalance())

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

But when I run it I get this:

```
b'{"code":100001,"msg":"","success":false,"timestamp":1675069039381}'
```

This is the doc [link](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/swapV2/introduce.html)

Comment: Hey, running into the same issue, did you manage to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the API is indicating that the request was unsuccessful and returned a code of 100001 with a success value of false. This means that there was some sort of signature authentication error in the request that was made.

The 100001 error code means that the signature authentication has failed. The signature is used to verify the authenticity of the request, so if the signature is incorrect, the request will fail.

There are a few things that could be causing the signature to fail:

1. Incorrect calculation of the signature: Make sure the code for generating the signature is correct and follows the requirements of the BingX API.
2. Incorrect encoding: Make sure the signature is properly encoded before being added to the request as a query parameter.
3. Incorrect secret key: Make sure the secret key used to generate the signature is correct and up-to-date.
4. Incorrect time stamp: Make sure the time stamp included in the request is correct and in the correct format.

You should carefully review the code and the API documentation to ensure that the signature is being generated correctly and that all required information is included in the request. If the issue persists, you may also want to reach out to the BingX API support team for additional assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please, check my code for generating signature? I spend a lot of times to fix it but I wasn't successful.

Comment: I edited my code as above. I think it's better now but still signature is wrong. Please help me it's very important for my job

Comment: I'm assuming you replaced the "MyApiKey" and "MySecretKey" with your actual keys, correct?

Comment: Yes. it's correct

Comment: In your Gensignature method, try removing the encoding to "utf-8". Both your keys are strings by default and I don't think its necessary to encode them as it returns that weird b sign in between, which might not be recognized by the hash algorithm.

Comment: It gives this error: TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

Comment: Actually hmac only accept bytes or bytearray

Comment: Do you know another way to fix it? @threadsurfer

Comment: Try using Java's .getBytes() method to convert it to Bytes

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as you when I put the `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET` in a dictionary in a `config.p`y file and used:

```py
from config import *
```

This imports all the data into your file. I did this to not leave the keys exposed in the program. I used `APIKEY=str(API_DETAILS.get('API_KEY'))` and `SECRETKEY=str(API_DETAILS.get('API_SECRET'))`. It did not work!.

```py
b'{"code":100413,"msg":"Incorrect apiKey","success":false,"timestamp":1688949058434}'
```

When I made it explicit in the code, using `APIKEY='XXX"` and `SECRETKEY="XXX"`, it worked. I don't know why because in both cases the `type(APIKEY)` is a string.

```py
b'{"code":0,"msg":"","data":{"balance":{"userId":"XXX","asset":"USDT","balance":"0.0000", "equity":"0.0000","unrealizedProfit":"0.0000","realisedProfit":"0.0000","availableMargin":"0.0000","usedMargin":"0.0000","freezedMargin":"0.0000"}}} '
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
import requests

# Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual Binance API key
headers = {'X-MBX-APIKEY': 'YOUR_API_KEY'}

# Make a GET request to the Binance account endpoint
response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account', headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    # Get the user's available balance for the specified asset
    asset_balance = [balance for balance in data['balances'] if balance['asset'] == 'BTC'][0]['free']
    print('User balance:', asset_balance)
else:
    # Handle the error
    print('Error:', response.text)
```

Comment: What you sent is used for binance api, not bingx api